# Need Help with a Fictional Modern Baltic Country’s Name?

Tags: culture, language, names

I want the name of the country to mean “eastern border/land”, but I’m not a professional in the Latvian/Eastern Baltic languages.

As an example, would it be Austgale or Austrumgale (gale meaning “border/end”, similar to Latgale)? Or something like Austzeme (zeme meaning “land”, similar to Vidzeme)? I’m not sure what derivation patterns would be accurate.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Estonia, Latvia, Lithuania..... it should definitely end with -ia

Comment: Names are arbitrary. You can name your nation whatever you want. Questions where the answer is entirely based on opinion are not a suitable for this site.

Comment: @sphennings OP has given clear boundaries for the name. They are not asking for a "good name", but for a "name that means X in language Y"

Comment: @L.Dutch Given the multitude of ways you could refer to a country as "eastern border/land" in English. What makes you think that there would be fewer answers amongst the multiple languages of the Baltic region?

Comment: I'm with @L.Dutch, here. He's trying to solve the same conundrum I had with my first book. You have a fictional country, but it has a vague ethnicity that you want to give the general feel of a group of real-world countries. In my case, I had a vaguely European city full of wizards, so I found a word that meant "wizard" in German and then appended a common "city" extension, thus Zauberton. This doesn't have to be accurate or realistic, it just has to sound right in the mind of your audience. OP is asking about this process.

Comment: I'd like this question to be kept open :) : The choice of the name has already been made, the issue lies in its translation, if we could say that. While the boundary of a better answer is blurrier than in other cases, there are still better answers than others, ones that will feel more... Natural? More natural to foreigners and 'specially for natives ^^.

Comment: @wokopa Those are the anglified names, though.

Answer (score 2):

In the Latvian language, the word for **"eastern border/land"** could be **"Austrumgale"** or **"Austrumzeme."**

The word **"Austrum"** means **"east"** in Latvian, and **"gale"** or **"zeme"** means **"border"** or **"land"**, respectively.

So **"Austrumgale"** would mean **"eastern border"** and **"Austrumzeme"** would mean **"eastern land."**

It's worth noting that the specific forms of the words may vary depending on the grammatical context and the specific Latvian dialect being used. If you would like to ensure the most accurate and appropriate form, I would recommend consulting with a native speaker or a professional in the Latvian language.

Comment: Note that the English names of the countries and regions in those parts of the world are usually derived from the early modern Latinized names; for example, it is Lithuania and not Lietuva, Courland and not Kurzeme, and Semigallia and not Zemgale.

Answer (score 1):

**Aestland.**

The map below shows the names of people that lived in various areas, not the names of the lands, but we can derive the place name from the people name.

[image: roman northern europe]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesti

> The Aesti (also Aestii, Astui or Aests) were an ancient people first
> described by the Roman historian Tacitus in his treatise Germania
> (circa 98 AD).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD5TS.png) According to Tacitus, the land of Aesti was located
> somewhere east of the Suiones (probably a progenitor group of modern
> Swedes)...
>
> During the 11th century Adam of Bremen, citing Einhard (who in the
> Vita Caroli Magni states "the Slavs and the Aisti live on the shores
> of the Eastern Sea"), mentions the coastal tribe as the Haisti, and
> refers to today's Estonia as Aestland

Benefits:
1:  Root confers it is east.
2:  Historically probably the same as Estonia (the root of which also confers east!)
3:  But no-one is really sure

> Despite the phonological similarity between Aestii and the modern day
> Estonia (Eesti), especially in popular etymologies, it has been argued
> that the two geographical areas are not contiguous and there are few,
> if any, direct historical links between them. The etymologies of Aesti
> and Eesti remain subjects of scholarly conjecture,

so you are less likely to offend any real people because of the shenanigans your fictonal Aestii get up to.

Comment: The "land" part seems unlikely within their own dialect. "Aestgale" more likely, but I am not a speaker of those languages.

Comment: Why not "Aestii" as labeled on the map?

Comment: @SRM - this map has the names of the people who live there, not country names; it would be weird to name a place a pleural.  Although "The Hamptons" so maybe?   Re Aestland - that was in the wikipedia article but Aestgale or Aestonia or Aestia could all be similar riffs.

Comment: I think the article you linked implies that "Aesti" could simply be the name given to that people by Tacitus and other roman writers (and it does sound like latin). Am I misreading something?

Comment: @Hankrecords - that was my understanding.  And so Aestland would be land of the Aestii just like England is land of the Engs and Netherlands is land of the Nethers.

Comment: I think it's important to point out then, since maybe OP does not have a roman-like/latin-sounding culture in their world